# Python - pandas, DataFrame look like Nan but the behavior is like number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

When i look or save `to_csv` my DataFrame I see a cell containing `NaN`, but when i use the same cell it behaves like a number. How comes?

```
In [84]: db['Category_1']['also']
Out[84]: 0.91652216992816438

In [85]: db.loc['also']
Out[85]: 
frequency     0.275729
TS_1              True
Category_1         NaN
Name: also, dtype: object

In [88]: db['Category_1'].sum()
Out[88]: 99.99999999999974

In [89]: db['Category_1']['also'] = 0
         db['Category_1'].sum()
Out[89]: 99.08347783007159
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: `NaN` has a dtype `float` the arithmetic operations will ignore the `NaN` values so what are you expecting here?

Comment: I expecting when i  save `to_save` or look on Variable explorer I get the number `0.9165...` and not `Nan`

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here.  The question is perfectly clear: the value of the frame at column `Category_1` and row `also` is 0.9165 according to #84 and #88-89, but the value shown in #85 is NaN, and the OP wants to know why, as explained in the very first sentence.  Since the OP uses chained assignment, and there are known issues where using chained assignment can leave a frame in an inconsistent state, I'd suspect something along those lines.

Comment: This is the way I add number to the column:

`for item in cat.word_dict:

    db['Category_1'][item] = cat.word_dict[item][1]`

Can I use a different way to fill my DF - that will overcome this bug? 

Thank you!

Comment: After i google "chained assignment issue", I found this solution. 
`db.loc[item,'Category_1'] = cat.word_dict[item][1]` and is gives much better performance